# Why do i get the same values in all pages in CI pagination?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, url, pagination

I'm kinda new in CI and i'm trying to create a proper pagination for my page.

I have the following model and controller and even if i manage to get the pagination links, when i visit the other pages i get the same entries again and again.

I also have applied an Ajax "GET" filtering for fetching results from db and i managed to reuse the url parameters when i change pages.

The problem is that i don't know if i should try to create an infinite scroll function or maintain the default CI pagination.

I'd like to hear your opinions too!

Thank you in advance!

```
public function get_filtered_pets($limit, $start){
 $this->db->order_by('pet_created_at', 'DESC');
 $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id = pets.pet_user_id');
 $this->db->join('pet_categories', 'pet_categories.pet_category_id = pets.category_id');

$pet_data = array();
if ( $this->input->get('petStatus') ) {
  $pet_data['pet_status'] = $this->input->get('petStatus');
}
if ( $this->input->get('petCategory') ) {
  $pet_data['category_id'] = $this->input->get('petCategory');
}
if ( $this->input->get('petGender') ) {
  $pet_data['pet_gender'] = $this->input->get('petGender');
}

if ( !empty($pet_data) ) {
  $this->db->where($pet_data);
}

$query = $this->db->get('pets');
if ($start > 0) {
  $this->db->last_query();
}

return $query->result_array();

}
```

And my controller

```
public function index(){

$query = $this->db->get('pets');
$pet_num = $query->num_rows();

$config = array();

$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "pets/index/";
$config["total_rows"] = $pet_num;
$config["per_page"] = 12;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;

$config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'page-link');
$config["full_tag_open"] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config["full_tag_close"] = '</ul>';
$config["first_link"] = "&laquo;";
$config["first_tag_open"] = "<li>";
$config["first_tag_close"] = "</li>";
$config["last_link"] = "&raquo;";
$config["last_tag_open"] = "<li>";
$config["last_tag_close"] = "</li>";
$config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '<li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '<li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data['pets'] = $this->pet_model->get_filtered_pets($config["per_page"], $page);

$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

//View files
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('pets/index', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the value of `$limit` and `$start` nowhere. See [Limiting or Counting Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results).

You should:

```
public function get_filtered_pets($limit, $start){

    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

    /* ... */

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

And also, when calling this function you have to multiply: per_page * page, to get the offset (starting index).

```
$this->pet_model->get_filtered_pets($config["per_page"], $page * $config["per_page"])
```

---

To count results correctly, I normally have two functions on model: "get($search, $offset)" and "count($search)".

The function `count` has exactly the same code on `get`, except the select fields.

See this code, I think you will get it: https://pastebin.com/dZG90Lzm.

ps: There's ways to optimize it and avoid duplicate code.

Comment: Still nothing.. I made those changes and the problem persists.
Here's the pastebin of the changed file..

https://pastebin.com/7pGj9dnQ

Comment: @HarrysR. What is the url of page 2?

Comment: @HarrysR. Put this `echo $this->db->last_query();` before `return $query->result_array()`

Comment: Well that's weird.. Or i'm kinda confused here.. 
I get SELECT * FROM `pets` JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `pets`.`pet_user_id` JOIN `pet_categories` ON `pet_categories`.`pet_category_id` = `pets`.`category_id` ORDER BY `pet_id` DESC LIMIT 24, 12
with last query...

Comment: Well i think i solved it (as you can check again in the pastebin), i think i was wrong about the calculation since i was using the page number: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955394/use-page-numbers-in-codeigniter-pagination-class

Comment: @HarrysR. Oh, an important thing I notice in your code. You have to count in the same way you select (join and where clauses), otherwise you will get wrong pages.

Comment: any help on that!? One thing i noticed is that if i filter the data (because i'm using jquery filtering with "GET" parameters), if the entries are as much as the per_page config i still get more pages even if the others are empty of data. 
Any ideas!?

Comment: I will take a look at it!
Thank you for your time!