# How to fix pagination issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

My pagination limit is 5 and i'm getting 5 posts per page. Now on Page 1 I have 5 posts, but when I go to Page 2 it skips 5 posts after first page and start second page with post #11 and from page 2 till end all posts are displayed properly. and then last page is empty.
(That means the posts 6 to 10 skipped)

I tried changes limit $this->global_limit = 5; to any other number. The problem persist same like If I change limit to 10 first page will display 10 posts then skip 11 to 20th post and start page 2 with post # 21.

```
    /**
     * Code in controller file
     */
            $this->global_limit = 5;
            $this->params['lang_id'] = $this->lang_id;
    $this->params['limit'] = $this->global_limit;
    $this->params['slug'] = $this->slug;

    /**
     * Code in Helper file
     */
function get_blog_posts($params, $category_rewrite)
{
    $CI = &get_instance();


    /**
     * Count and get all the posts
     */
    $posts_count = $CI->blog->getPosts($params, TRUE);
    $posts = $CI->blog->getPosts($params);


    /**
     * Pagination
     */
    $config['base_url'] = $category_rewrite['slug'] . 'page/';
    $config['total_rows'] = (int)$posts_count;
    $config['per_page'] = isset($params['limit']) ? (int)$params['limit'] : FALSE;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
    $config['num_links'] = 10;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['suffix'] = $CI->uri->getpath() ? '/?' . $CI->uri->getpath() : '';
    $config['first_url'] = $category_rewrite['slug'];

    $CI->pagination->initialize($config);
    $pagination = $CI->pagination->create_links();

    /**
     * Code in model file
     */
  public function getPosts($params, $count = FALSE)
{
    $params = array_merge($this->params, $params);

    extract($params);

    $this->db->join('blog_posts_langs as bpl', 'bp.id = bpl.post_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('blog_categories as bc', 'bc.id = bp.category_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('blog_categories_multi as bcm', 'bcm.post_id = bp.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('url_rewrite as urwr', 'urwr.url_type = "blog_post" AND urwr.element_id = bp.id AND urwr.lang_id = '. $lang_id, 'left');

    if ($category) {
        $this->db->where('(bc.id = "' . $category . '" OR bc.parent_id IN (' . $in_categories . ') OR bcm.category_id = '. $category .' )');
    }


    if ($lang_id) {
        $this->db->where('bpl.lang_id', $lang_id);
    }


    if ($search) {
        $this->db->like('bpl.title', $search);
    }

    if ($tag) {
        $this->db->like('urwr.meta_keywords', $tag);
    }

    if ($status) {
        $this->db->where('bp.status', $status);
    }


    if ($order_by) {
        $this->db->order_by($order_by);
    }


    if ($count) {
        $this->db->select('bp.id');
        $this->db->group_by('bp.id');
        return $this->db->count_all_results('blog_posts as bp');

    } else {

        if ($id) {
            $this->db->select('bp.id as post_id, bp.category_id as post_category, bp.author as post_author, 
                               bp.video as post_video, bp.post_published, bp.status as post_status, 
                               bpl.lang_id as post_language, bpl.title as post_title, bpl.brief as post_brief, 
                               bpl.content as post_content, urwr.views as post_views');
            $this->db->where('bp.id', $id);
            $this->db->group_by('bpl.lang_id');
        }else{

            $this->db->select('bp.id as post_id, 
                               bp.author as post_author, 
                               DATE_FORMAT(bp.post_created, "'. $date_format .'") as post_created, 
                               DATE_FORMAT(bp.post_updated, "'. $date_format .'") as post_updated, 
                               DATE_FORMAT(bp.post_published, "'. $date_format .'") as post_published, 
                               bp.status as post_status, 
                               bp.video as post_video,
                               bp.category_id as post_category_id,
                               bpl.title as post_title,
                               bpl.source as post_source, 
                               bpl.brief as post_brief, 
                               bpl.content as post_content,
                               bcl.name as post_category_name,
                               urwr.slug as post_url, urwr.views as post_views', false);
            $this->db->where('bcl.lang_id', $lang_id);
            $this->db->group_by('bp.id');
        }

        if ($limit) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        }

        $this->db->join('blog_categories_langs as bcl', 'bp.category_id = bcl.category_id', 'left');

        return $this->db->get('blog_posts as bp')->result_array();
    }

}
```

Comment: where is `$limit` defined ?

Comment: its in controller  $this->global_limit = 5;

Answer (score 0):

For pagination,

Page 1: 0 - 4   (index starts with 0)

page 2: 5 - 9

You need to calculate start value as follows

```
$start = ($page-1) * $limit;
```

Then it will work properly.

You need to add this code in the controller file after

```
$this->params['limit'] = $this->global_limit;
$start = $this->uri->segment(4);
$this->params['start'] = $start
```

You may need to check the segment value where you get page number or start offset. If you get Page number then you need to apply the above calculation to get the start offset from page number. Also the segment number can be varied based on your url parameters.

Comment: Where to add this line of code in model file 
if ($limit) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        }

Comment: If I add it $this->db->limit($limit, ($page-1) * $limit); 
OR
$start = ($page-1) * $limit;
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
Its givving database error

Comment: Do you get `$page` as a parameter in pagination links

Comment: No its not there, could you please guide me where to add and what will be the code

Comment: Check with uri segments `$this->uri->segment(3)` which gives pages number / start offset. Number can be 2 to 5 as per segments.

Comment: Also, I found similar answer in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955394/use-page-numbers-in-codeigniter-pagination-class check that too.

Comment: Message: Using $this when not in object context. This Error is comming After using above solution

Answer (score 0):

Edit in Model file worked for me. Below is my code snippet. Many Thanks to @balakrishnan

```
      $page = $this->uri->segment(5,1);
        if ($limit) {
            $this->db->limit($limit,($page-1) * $limit);
        }
```